# How to delete cookies for a specific site

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, cookies

I need a button or bookmarklet to delete the cookies from the current context. Clearing the cache would be another option.

Specifically, I am logged into too many Google sites and have multiple accounts active. If I log out, it logs everything out.

I want to delete the cookies for a given context (eg. on `music.google.com`, delete cookies for `music.google.com` but leave cookies for ever other site like `accouts.google.com`, thus refreshing the page prompts me for which account I'd like to use.

Comment: Depending on how Google account logins work, that might not even be possible at all.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not fond of web development but I created wrote a bit of JavaScript to do it, but it didn't delete the header only cookies.  I thought maybe extensions might have more control

Answer (score 131, accepted):

1. Click the document icon next to the URL.
2. Click the "... from this site" link under the **Cookies** section.
   [image: Google Chrome - site properties]
3. Highlight the cookie and choose **Remove**. You can also **Block** the whole site.
   [image: Google Chrome - Cookies set by this page]

Comment: This is a fantastic tool as it also has other information about the domain and you can change the security from here.  I'm glad Google has added something official for managing your data on a specific site.

Comment: Thank you! I had the same kind of problem, only not Chrome, but Firefox, and this tutorial has helped me to figure out what steps I should take in Firefox!

Answer (score 20):

You can do it through Chrome settings. Just go to **Preferences** -> **Options** -> **Under the Hood** -> **Content settings** -> **All cookies and site data...**

There you can filter single domain from the list and delete the ones you like.

Comment: This option is now unavailable.

Comment: It's still available.  After entering a domain name to filter, click the button, misleadingly named "Remove All".  In reality it'll delete only filtered items.

Comment: Or just go to `chrome://settings/siteData`, the alternative to `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData`.

Comment: Preferences -> Options -> Under the Hood doesn't appear to be present in recent chrome versions.

Answer (score 9):

The bookmarklet from http://ostermiller.org/bookmarklets/cookies.html should work without modification. Just visit the target website first

```
javascript:void((function(){var%20a,b,c,e,f;f=0;a=document.cookie.split(";%20");for(e=0;e<a.length&&a[e];e++){f++;for(b="."+location.host;b;b=b.replace(/^(?:%5C.|[^%5C.]+)/,"")){for(c=location.pathname;c;c=c.replace(/.$/,"")){document.cookie=(a[e]+";%20domain="+b+";%20path="+c+";%20expires="+new%20Date((new%20Date()).getTime()-1e11).toGMTString());}}}alert("Expired%20"+f+"%20cookies");})())
```

Comment: Per the documentation, it only clears cookes for THAT PAGE: "Clears all cookies for the current page."

Answer (score 4):

In Chrome 60+ it's now in the dev tools (F12) - Application tab - Clear Site Data

Answer (score 3):

In Chrome 63, you can open this page and get sites listed separately:

```
chrome://settings/siteData
```

Just pick the site you're interested in and you'll see all cookies (or other artifacts like cache, localstorage, etc.). Way easier than navigating various menus ;)

Please note that the above URL is bookmarkable, which means, you can either bookmark the above URL or even bookmark an individual page like this:

```
chrome://settings/cookies/detail?site=accounts.google.com
```

After that, you can use whatever method or extension you want to trigger the bookmark (menu, bookmark toolbar, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

1. Install **Web Developer** extension ([Chrome](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/download/chrome/) , [Firefox](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/download/firefox/) , [Opera](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/download/opera/))
2. go to cookies tab -> Delete **Domain Cookies** like below screenshot

[image: web-developer addon delete cookie extension]

Answer (score 1):

I found a good and easy to use extension for the same. [Remove cookies for site.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/remove-cookies-for-site/lmfdblomdpkcniknaenceeogpgepocmm?hl=en-GB)

Its description:

> DESCRIPTION:
>   Click the broken cookie and all cookies for the current site will be deleted.
>
> I built this extension because it was simply missing. As a developer I need a quick way to clean all cookies for the current site.

Answer (score 1):

In **Mozilla Firefox**, I would follow these steps.

1. Click the lock/security icon next to the URL
2. Select 'More information'. On the securities tab, click on 'view cookies'.
3. Select the cookies to delete, and use 'remove selected cookies' option. Or you could simply use 'remove all cookies' (which is matching the current URL).

For detailed steps (not the one above),

[See Firefox documentation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-cookies-remove-info-websites-stored)

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671057/firefox-addon-to-remove-cache-and-cookies-of-one-domain)