# How can I clear cookies for a single site?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

Sometimes a webapp breaks for whatever reason, and I need to clear my cookies in order to use it again. I wind up clearing all of my cookies, which is a pain, because I then have to log back in to all the sites I use.

I've tried <kbd>F12</kbd>, and right-clicking on the refresh icon to empty the cache, but that's not always enough and doesn't seem to remove cookies.

How can I clear cookies for a particular site, while keeping my other ones?

Comment: Fast version here: http://superuser.com/a/781848/116192

Answer (score 360, accepted):

Copy paste `chrome://settings/content/cookies` in the Omnibox ( or Click on Chrome menu → Settings → Advanced → Content Settings → All cookies and site data). Scroll to the bottom, Search for the site & then delete.

thanks to [RavanH](https://superuser.com/questions/548096/how-can-i-clear-cookies-for-a-single-site/548097?noredirect=1#comment1793091_548097), [Amalgovinus](https://superuser.com/questions/548096/how-can-i-clear-cookies-for-a-single-site/548097?noredirect=1#comment2002024_548097) & [Ian Boyd](https://superuser.com/questions/548096/how-can-i-clear-cookies-for-a-single-site/548097?noredirect=1#comment2838638_548097) for the updated answer.

Comment: Fast version here: http://superuser.com/a/781848/116192