# What happened to specific site cookies in the newest Chrome? (Version 59.0.3071.115)

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I noticed today that my Chrome installation no longer lets me search for and delete site specific cookies as it did yesterday and before. I've had a shortcut on my shortcuts bar for months that links to chrome://settings/cookies and that now gets truncated to just chrome://settings and searching for cookies now takes me to a popup that only lets me delete ALL cookies for a variety of periods but shows no obvious means to get site specific. Is that still possible in some obscure, deeper region?

My apologies ... the answer to this question: [How can I clear cookies for a single site?](https://superuser.com/questions/548096/how-can-i-clear-cookies-for-a-single-site?rq=1) still works and I hadn't managed to find it with my other searches before posting my question.