# Chrome: per-site MathJax settings

Tags: google-chrome, mathjax

Does Chrome support per-site MathJax settings? I think I may have broken the Mathjax settings for `localhost`, but don't know where to find them.

MathJax formulae on one site are not displaying in Chrome. The text between `$` is instead shown literally in grey, but without the `$`.

This webpage dynamically generated by a [vim markdown previewer](https://github.com/iamcco/markdown-preview.vim) with [Mathjax plugin](https://github.com/iamcco/mathjax-support-for-mkdp), accessed via a server running on `127.0.0.1`.

Formulae used to display just fine, but I was playing with settings, and probably broke something.

The same renderer generates output which displays correctly in Firefox, and Chrome can display other MathJax sites just fine.

I'm suspecting a per-site setting somewhere.

If I right-click on the gray text the default context menu appears rather than the MathJax context menu.

Are there per-site MathJax settings in Chrome?

Comment: MathJax stores a cookie with user settings. Try clearing it.

Answer (score 1):

Prompted by Peter Krautzberger's comment above, I followed the steps in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/548097/365890) to clear the cookies for `127.0.0.1` and everything is now ok.

Comment: Worked for me. I played around with settings and accidentally "Activated" the Accessibility feature. I was seeing equations in latex in chrome, while equations were rendering properly in Firefox. Removing cookies for the site fixed it for me. Thanks a ton.