# Does Google Chrome have some primary key in its cookies database?

Tags: google-chrome, database, cookies, utc

I am writing some scanner for Google Chrome cookies, as stored in [a SQLite database](https://superuser.com/questions/459426/where-does-chrome-store-its-cookie-file). It also has an option to delete cookies, however I didn't find any ID field. The most similar is `creation_utc`, I don't have much info about it, but I found out that it is some kind of timestamp. I would like to know if this value is unique or not.

I need this because while deleting some cookies I use a few fields, and it is not an optimal way to do it. If `creation_utc` is unique, it would take less time to delete the cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, each combination of domain and path can only have one cookie with a specific name. (If a server sends a new cookie, the old one is replaced.)

So even when the database has another primary key (like you're suggesting in your own answer), I still feel the domain and path should be the real primary key.

Comment: I used [this](http://coderstoolbox.net/unixtimestamp/) time-stamp converter and found that value in database cannot be converted into time format because is too big. So I think `Google Chrome` uses some advanced time-stamp and counts milliseconds, it let use this as primary key.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer. I used query: `PRAGMA table_info(cookies)` it gave result all columns, their types and etc. One of the attributes was called `pk` (primary key). All columns had set to 0, but `creation_utc` is set to 1, so it is primary key.

Comment: This is, technically, correct; `.schema Cookies` tells you the same. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `creation_utc` = [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) when the cookie was created. So no, it doesn't guarantee uniqueness.

If you just want to delete cookies for a single site, you can use [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/366483/how-to-delete-cookies-for-a-specific-site/366493#366493).